# How to search by key word list in file content for a drive or directory

Tags: r, bash

I have a text file containing a list of key words. I need to search a drive (and recursively its subfolders) containing millions of files in different formats by those key words in the filename AND their content.

The desired result would be a list of the files containing those keywords and their location.

Is there a way to achieve that with bash or an R script? I was told that bash would be way too slow to execute for that quantity of files, hence I thought about R.

Any suggestions on functions that could achieve that would be appreciated.

Comment: `Catfish` is a handy file searching tool for Linux

Comment: When you say "filename", does that include the directories? or just the base of the file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to search a drive (and recursively its subfolders) containing millions of files in different formats by those key words in the filename AND their content.
> The desired result would be a list of the files containing those keywords and their location.

Using bash is perfect for this situation.

```bash
for item in ($cat file) ; do grep -rni "$item" /search_path ; done
```

search might take a while tho.

Comment: Thank you! I'll see how it performs...